# rendering style symbol (star) separately, not on the map, Openlayers

Tags: symbology, openlayers-2, style, rendering

I try to create a legend for the map separately in a different div.

How could I render a symbol (star e.g.) somewhere else in html, not only on the map with OpenLayers?

I guess I have to call `OpenLayers.Renderer.symbol.star` and display it elsewhere, but I couldn't figure out which method should be used...

The most perfect solution would be to get the exact styling properties like on the map...
Is there a way for it?

Comment: Ok, there is a layer.renderer object, and there is a lot of possibilities in this objet to define die div id, but it still does not render in the new defined div. I think it is much more complicated than just to modify the size and the div on that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a vector layer you could create a vector legend
(http://api.geoext.org/1.0/examples/vector-legend.html ) . If you are using WMS-layer you can use a getlegend-request.

Edit1:
here as jsfiddle about how to use OpenLayers.Renderer to create a static "map" as a legend.
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/g8LncceL/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the legend has to be fully customizable and the project is quite big to build in geoext at this stage. So I can't use this possability... I have the assumption that I have to create the symbols again with svg separately...

Comment: yes, you can build them with SVG or the OpenLayers.renderer inside a static mal that acts as a legend. I have added a jsfiddle above.